# How to set custom user claims for Firebase Auth user in Vercel edge functions?

Tags: node.js, firebase, next.js, firebase-authentication, vercel

Firebase admin SDK is not supported on [Vercel edge functions](https://vercel.com/docs/concepts/functions/edge-functions/limitations#most-node.js-apis-are-not-available) so how can I set [custom user claims](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/custom-claims#set_and_validate_custom_user_claims_via_the_admin_sdk) in Firebase auth user if I have uid and id token?

Comment: It's unclear to me why you'd want to set a custom claim in an edge function. I think custom claims are usually added to a user auth record only when they change, like "isPremium" or "isAdmin", and that can be done anywhere where the admin SDK is supported including some CLI script, but to me doesn't seem like something you'd want to do constantly or as part of an edge function.

Comment: I'm setting isPremium in edge function (it's a webhook)

Comment: I see. I think your only option is to move the code to a Vercel serverless function instead of the edge runtime. Setting an isPremium flag in response to a webhook callback doesn't seem like something super time-critical anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I find it funny that @machavity deleted OP's answer. I'm mentioning the solution again:

`setCustomUserClaims` method can be used from [next-firebase-auth-edge](https://github.com/awinogrodzki/next-firebase-auth-edge) library.

For more details:
https://github.com/awinogrodzki/next-firebase-auth-edge/issues/32